# Looking to remove a space in one of the results while performing multiple mid searches on a column

Tags: excel

I am trying to embed a `SUBSTITUTE` in my function, but I am not sure where to incorporate it. I am trying to extract just the text "`Scrumactiviteiten`" but in the source data sometimes a space will be in there. A sample:

**Column A**

```
1 Team xxxx 2018-17 Scrumactiviteiten 123 and then something  

2 Team xxxx 2018-17 Scrum activiteiten 123 and then something
```

**Column B** (My formula)

```
1 Scrumactiviteiten

2 Scrum activiteiten
```

The function I used to extract it (ignore the "`Balans`" search please):

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(MID(A1;SEARCH("Scrum activiteiten";A1;1);18);
MID(A1;SEARCH("Scrumactiviteiten";A1;1);17));MID(A1;SEARCH("Balans";A1;1);10));" ")
```

This works fine, but to remove the space I tried to embed a `SUBSTITUTE` where I use the mid search result as the old text and provide "`Scrumactiviteiten`" as the new text:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(A24;((MID(A24;SEARCH("Scrum activiteiten";A24;1);18)));"Scrumactiviteiten");MID(A24;SEARCH("Scrumactiviteiten";A24;1);17));MID(A24;SEARCH("Balans";A24;1);10));" ")
```

The result however is a copy of the full string. I also tried putting the substitute before the search but that would not work either. I am pretty new to Excel formula's and I think I messed up the order or just plain don't understand how I embed a `SUBSTITUTE` in the formula I created. Some explanation would be much appreciated on what I'm doing wrong! Thank you in advance,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not providing the correct arguments to the function, try this formula:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(((MID(A24;SEARCH("Scrum activiteiten";A24;1);18)));" ";"");MID(A24;SEARCH("Scrumactiviteiten";A24;1);17));MID(A24;SEARCH("Balans";A24;1);10));" ")
```

To use `SUBSTITUTE` you first provide the string in which you want to replace something, the next two arguments are the string you want replaced and the string you want to replace it with. So for example `=SUBSTITUTE("Scrum activiteiten";" ";"")` returns `Scrumactiviteiten` as the space `" "` is replaced with an empty string `""`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it worked perfectly. I think I tried with those arguments as well, but probably messed up the order.. Cheers!